# Extract dynamic list to sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365

I'm trying to get a list of values from a table.
I have a column with a list of sites and a column with the month name which this site opened the first time:

Site Name ==>List of sites in one column   Opened in==>List of months in one column

In Addition, I have 12 sheets (1 per month):
Jan sheet - I want to extract the sites that opened in January to appear in the January sheet only

Feb sheet - I want to extract the sites that opened in Jan+Feb

March sheet - I want to extract the sites that opened in Jan+Feb+March etc..

It's important that sites that opened in Mar won't appear in Jan/feb

In Addition near each site, I need to fill in the number of visitors on Friday/Sat and I have a calculated column that counts the total visitors and a column that summarize the total expected payment on each day by site==>example to a formula which calculated the total sum of payment per each Friday in Jan: If the site was closed so I write "CLOSE" in D,F,H,J,L cells and then its 0 for payment. If I write 0 in the cell so I should expect 1500$ etc

```
IF(ISNONTEXT($D4),MAX($D4*Jan!$C4,1500),0)+
IF(ISNONTEXT($F4),MAX($F4*Jan!$C4,1500),0)+
IF(ISNONTEXT($H4),MAX($H4*Jan!$C4,1500),0)+
IF(ISNONTEXT($J4),MAX($J4*Jan!$C4,1500),0)+
IF(ISNONTEXT($L4),MAX($L4*Jan!$C4,1500),0)
```

How should I build this table in each sheet properly in order to avoid a mixup in calc columns when Im trying to sort the extracted list of sites

Thank you!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bj5uT.png ==>1st sheet

https://i.stack.imgur.com/a69SE.png ==>Jan sheet where I fill the number of visitors per site

Comment: Some sample date and expected result would make it easier to answer

Comment: Hello @crisneilsen, thanks!